# How to unit test a factory with Jasmine and Angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have searched the internet but was not able to find what I need. Basically I have a factory declared as follows:

```
angular.module('puFactories').factory('RestFactory', function ($http, $q) {
return {
    getAccountInfo: getAccountInfo,
    getFriendsInfos: getFriendsInfos
}
}
```

the `'puFactories'` module has no dependencies. What I want is to create an instance of this factory in a jasmine unit test. I tried the following:

```
describe('Unit: RestFactory', function() {
    var factory;
    beforeEach(module('puFactories'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_RestFactory_){
        factory = _RestFactory_;
    }));
}
```

However I get the following exception when running karma:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: RestFactoryProvider <- RestFactory
```

**EDIT:**

Okay, so it seems that I need to clarify the code above. My module is properly declared and the application as a whole is working. I have simply splitted the factories and controllers in different files. The factory also returns and object in my application I have simplified the code as it is not relevant.

**EDIT 2:**

I also tried with

```
beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
        factory = $injector.get('RestFactory');
    }));
```

Simply the object being returned is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so, after too much time spend on solving issue on this project I decided to start out with a clean one. I have included all the needed frameworks in this project. I have added it to a repo in github for easier use in future since it takes quite a while to configure all that. Here is the repo: https://github.com/fatalerrorbg/MobileAppBase

Comment: Well, that is an interesting minus, I would appreciate at least a comment.